# How can I manipulate a css animation to act like a :hover with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this css animation:

HTML:

```
<div class="container" id="cont">
  <div class="box show"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  transition-duration: 1500ms;
  transition-property: width;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container:hover .box {
  width: 500px;
}

.show {
  background: #9CEAEF;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

And i have a javascript countdown, when is reach to 10 i want to show this CSS animation with some text on it and stay there for 8 seconds than to release back. I don't know how to search about that, tried over one hour and not figure out.

```
function updateCountdown() {
    var timeLeft = Math.round(vid.duration) - Math.round(vid.currentTime);
    if (timeLeft == 10 && shown == false) {
        console.log(timeLeft)
        // here i want to trigger the css 
        shown = true
    }else if (timeLeft < 2) {
        vid.removeEventListener('timeupdate', updateCountdown);
        // here i want to relase the css back
    }
}
```

here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/burlacu-daniel-robert/pen/bGEyYzN

Comment: The title of your question does not seem to be talking about the same problem in the description. What does `:hover` has to do with your problem?

Comment: @Sapinder updated.

Comment: @Shadi i was thought is the best example, maybe is not. I want my css to act like a :hover when i trigger it (like the mouse is hover) and when i want to release to act like the mouse is not hover anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change or alter the actual `:hover` selector through `Javascript.` You can, however, use `mouseenter` to change the style, and revert back on `mouseleave`

Comment: I don't need `:hover` in my css, i want to know the alternative way to launch this css when i need and close it back when i need and the animation to be the same like `:hover` one. I will check about `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo classes like :hover never refer to an element, but to any element that satisfies the conditions of the stylesheet rule. You need to edit the stylesheet rule, append a new rule, or add a new stylesheet that includes the new :hover rule.

```
var css = 'table td:hover{ background-color: #00ff00 }';
var style = document.createElement('style');

if (style.styleSheet) {
    style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```